# problem on differentiation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, implicit-differentiation

**show that $\cos x=x^2$ has exactly one solution in $\left(0,π/2\right)$ by the concept of differentiation**
let,$f\left(x\right)=\cos x-x^2$
first i assume that $f\left(x\right)$ has more than one solution.Suppose a&b are solution where $a<b$.Now,by rolle's theorem on $\left[a,b\right]$ i got a contradiction.Hence i can say that $f\left(x\right)$ has atmost one solution but how can i show that $f\left(x\right)$ has exactly one solution

Comment: hint: use intermediate value theorem: $f(0)=1$, $f(\pi/2)=-\pi^2/4$

Comment: @Vasya that means there is one solution, but not that there is exactly one solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Assume F(x) = **cos(x)-x<sup>2</sup>**. Lets Analyse this function.

- *Derivative* of this function turns out to be : **F '(x) =  - sin(x) - 2*x**
- *Double Derivative* of this function turns out to be : **F ''(x) =  - cos(x) - 2**

Now, **F ''(x) is always negative** in *interval [0, pie/2]*, since -cos(x) lies in [-1,0]. So *F ''(x) is bound to lie in [-3, -2]*.

This implies, **F '(x) is a strictly decreasing function in interval [0, pie/2]**, with max value at 0, which is F '(0) = 0.

*So, we can say that F '(x) is always negative in interval (0, pie/2].*

This implies, **F (x) is strictly decreasing function** in (0, pie/2]. Now F(0) = 1, So **F(0<sup>+</sup>) is 1** *since function is continuous*.

And **F(pie/2) = -(pie<sup>2</sup>/4)**. This implies ***F, being a strictly decreasing function***, should cross 'X-axis' exactly once in [0, pie/2], **since F(0<sup>+</sup>) > 0 and F(pie/2) < 0**. Hence, unique root exists.

Therefore, cos(x) = x<sup>2</sup>, only at a unique point in interval [0, pie/2].